# Google places autocomplete & Blur problems

Tags: jquery, google-places-api

I have a form that implements Google Places to autocomplete and populate other text fields.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.noEnterSubmit').keypress(function(e){
            if ( e.which == 13 ) return false;
        });

        var updateAddress = {

        autocomplete: new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#Subscription_address")[0], {types: ['geocode']}),

        event: function(){
            var self = this;    
            google.maps.event.addListener(self.autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = self.autocomplete.getPlace(),
                    address = place.address_components,
                    streetAddress = '',
                    suburb = '',
                    state = '',
                    zip = '',
                    country = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
                    var addressType = address[i].types[0];

                    if (addressType == 'subpremise') {
                        streetAddress += address[i].long_name + '/';
                    }
                    if (addressType == 'street_number') {
                        streetAddress += address[i].long_name + ' ';
                    }
                    if (address[i].types[0] == 'route') {
                        streetAddress += address[i].long_name;
                    }
                    if (addressType == 'locality') {
                        suburb = address[i].long_name;
                    }
                    if (addressType == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                        state = address[i].long_name;
                    }
                    if (addressType == 'postal_code') {
                        zip = address[i].long_name;
                    }
                    if (addressType == 'country') {
                        country = address[i].long_name;
                    }
                }

                // update the textboxes
                setTimeout(function(){$('#Subscription_address').val(streetAddress).blur(function(e){
                    this.value = this.streetAddress;
                });},50);
                $('#Subscription_city').val(suburb);
                $('#Subscription_state').val(state);
                $('#Subscription_zip').val(zip);
                $('#Subscription_country').val(country);
            });

        }
    };

    updateAddress.event();

    });
    </script>
    </head> 

<input class="noEnterSubmit input-large" name="Subscription[address]" id="Subscription_address" type="text">
```

I am blocking the form from submitting on enter keypress.  It is only when the user enter keypress then focus off of the text field does the #Subscription_address reset and the Google Places API shows an "Undefined" value for #Subscription_address.

Currently tab keypress and mouse selection as a blur event work as expected to populate other fields and retain only the streetAddress in the #Subscription_address field.

Using JQuery how do I allow the user to select autocomplete result by using enter keypress then focus off the text field and retain selected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       // update the textboxes
        setTimeout(function(){$('#Subscription_address').val(streetAddress).blur(function(e){
            this.value = streetAddress;
        });},50);
```

I needed to remove this.streetAddress after blur function.  this had a different context when in the DOM of the dropdown.